# why does the output of core.logic give the same value repeated?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

I tried this in core.logic

```
(require [clojure.core.logic :as l])

(l/run* [q]
  (l/fresh [a b c]
    (l/membero a [1])
    (l/membero b [4 5])
    (l/membero c [1 2])
    (l/== q [a b])))
```

expecting the result to be `[1 4] [1 5]`

but it was `[1 4] [1 4] [1 5] [1 5]`

then I started playing with it and found this:

```
(require [clojure.core.logic :as l])

(l/run* [q]
  (l/fresh [a b c]
    (l/membero a [1])
    (l/membero b [4 5])
    (l/membero c [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1])
    (l/== q [a b])))
```

```
 ;; => ([1 4] [1 4] [1 4] [1 5] [1 4] [1 4] [1 5] [1 4] [1 5] [1 4] [1 5] [1 5] [1 5] [1 5])
```

where there is a `[1 5]` interspersed with `[1 4]`

what is happening? is this repetition thing supposed to be a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the usage of the logic variable `c` which is not required as it is not being unified with `q`. If you remove `c` then you will get desired result. Basically you need to understand how the substitution works in core.logic to understand why you are getting these duplicate results because of `c`.

At a high level the process is like searching a tree for solutions, in this case each element in the vector which is `membero` with `c` leads to a node in the search tree and that causes duplicate results because for each node introduced by `c` probable values leads to correct result as `c` isn't used in the unification `(l/== q [a b])`

Comment: This answer is correct. c contributes more possibilities, but we aren't reifying it's value so it only appears as if we're getting repeated result.